# set class='selected ' in more than one option tag (list/menu)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, logic

Sorry, I want to ask a newbie question :)

I have PHP scripts like this :

```
<select id="member">
 <?php
  $sql   = " select id,name from member order by name ";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {             
 ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
 <?php
  }
 ?>                
</select>
```

then the result will be generating html like this

```
<select id="member">
 <option value="1">Jon Skeet</option>
 <option value="2">Marc Gravell</option>
 <option value="3">Darin Dimitrov</option>
</select>
```

my question is, actually I have 2 tables in mysql, first is **member** table and second **member_invited** table.
in **member** table:
**id** | **name**
---------------
00  | Jon Skeet
01  | Marc Gravell
02  | Darin Dimitrov

then in **member_invited** table:
**id** | **name**
---------------
00  | Jon Skeet
02  | Darin Dimitrov

within this two table
I want to make my list like this:
(look at class="selected" is in option tag that member has invited)

```
<select id="member">
 <option value="1">Jon Skeet</option>
 <option value="2" class="selected">Marc Gravell</option>
 <option value="3" class="selected">Darin Dimitrov</option>
</select>
```

please feel free to using javascript or jquery,, or maybe I can solve it just by using PHP ? 
many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do it in MySQL with a join to `member_invited` table and then extend your while loop regarding `is_invited` flag from resultset

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT x.id,x.name,IFNULL(y.id,0) AS is_invited FROM member x LEFT JOIN member_invited y ON x.id=y.id ORDER BY x.name";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {             
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"<?php if ($row['is_invited']>0) { echo " class=\"selected\""; } ?>><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: @rabudde or someone else, I want to ask litle question related to rabudde's answer.. i have member with id '0000' (char 4).. rabudde's code is work awsome,, but only this id can't catch :p '0000'. do you know why? hehehe trust me i'm very newbie :p

Comment: there is a member with id `0000`? so it's not an integer value? I don't understand your question correct. In which table is this id and what should it catch?

Comment: ow, it solved now,, i just make litle change to your query: IFNULL(y.id,-1) AS is_invited  -> and on list menu i do if ($row['is_invited']>=0) :) sory :p @rabudde i was edited my question, look at the id on the table,, many thanks

Comment: ahhhh, ok, so `<?php if ($row['is_invited']>0)` couldn't work, because PHP casts `0000` to integer value `0`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$("#member option").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
   if($this.val() == "2" || $this.val() == "3"){
      $this.addClass("selected");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like this to enable multiple selection :

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

And it's more clever to do what you want server-side...

Comment: He wants to set `class="selected"` and not the attribute `selected`